# Closing All other Accordion buttons except the one that is active

Tags: javascript, html

I have spent roughly an hour looking through stack-overflow answers looking for a solution to my problem. I have been unsuccessful in my attempts so now I will ask showing exactly the code I am working with. The Code is originally from w3schools.

Due to the amount of data that is going to be displayed in each section, it only makes sense to close them after the user is done reading other wise yup could be scrolling for a while.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** tl:dr I want to make it so only one of the accordions is active at a time and hide the content of the rest.

**Styling**

```
 <style>
 .fom {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 1;
   max-width: 700px;
   background: #fff;
   margin: 0 auto 100px;
   padding: 45px;
   text-align: center;
   box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
   background-image: url('pelican.jpg');

 }
 button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
button.accordion:after {
    content: '\02795'; /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
    font-size: 5px;
    color: #777;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2796"; /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
   <div class="fom">
 <h2>Police SOP's </h2>
 <p>These SOP's will be updated frequently so check them often</p>

 <button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
 <div class="panel">
   <p><?php echo$row['loadout']; ?></p>
 </div>

 <button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
 <div class="panel">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
 </div>

 <button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
 <div class="panel">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
 </div>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
 var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + 'px';
    }
  }
}
 </script>
```

The styling is wrapped in a head tag, and all the main html and script is wrapped in the body tag

Comment: Provide a jsFiddle please.

Comment: This is much easier with jquery - are you interested in a jquery solution or javascript only?

Comment: I am open to both, but have been supplied with an answer in javascript that works perfectly, thanks for quick response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working example with minor changes in your code:

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
   for (let i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].classList.remove('active');
        acc[i].style.maxHeight = null;
        acc[i].nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
    }
    this.style.maxHeight = this.scrollHeight+'px';
    this.classList.add('active');
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
     panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + 'px'
    
  }
}
```

```css
.fom {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 700px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  background-image: url('pelican.jpg');
}

button.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

button.accordion:after {
  content: '\02795';
  /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
  font-size: 5px;
  color: #777;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after {
  content: "\2796";
  /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
}

div.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="fom">
  <h2>Police SOP's </h2>
  <p>These SOP's will be updated frequently so check them often</p>

  <button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>
      <?php echo$row['loadout']; ?>
    </p>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
```

NOTE: the same thing would be much easier if you use jQuery. Give it a shot.

**Update**: **@Craig Mason** solution on the comment has an handled closing the active accordion. https://jsfiddle.net/at9wjbde/1/ is the fiddle that he mentioned

Comment: This is perfect Thanks, I have never used jQuery and may think about looking into it.

Comment: One quick Question, how do I then make it so upon clicking the already active one it closes?

Comment: active button closing JS only solution: https://jsfiddle.net/at9wjbde/1/

Comment: @Craig Mason You did it before I saw Eric McHogan comment :). Thanks for putting in the fiddle. Up voted ur comment and have updated my answer mentioning about your solution.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand correctly, you want the content below every accordion button to be hidden unless the button is pushed. One way you could do this is to add an `active` class to the currently clicked button, like so:

```
acc[i].onclick = function() {
    var accs = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion');
    for (let i = 0; i < accs.length; ii++) {
        accs[i].classList.remove('active');
    }

    acc[i].classList.add('active');
}
```

And then in your CSS, you could automatically hide all the content after non-active buttons like so:

```
.accordion:not(.active) + .panel {
     display: none;
 }
```

`+` is used to select the element that directly follows the preceding selector.

Comment: All the content below is hidden unless the button is active already, what I want to do is make it so that only one accordion is set as active at a time. sorry for the confusion, will edit OP to make it clearer.

Comment: Right, this code does that. Note the `accs[i].classList.remove('active')`. There will only ever be a single active accordion button because clicking any given accordion unsets the `active` class on every button, then sets it on the single clicked button.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned your interest in a jquery solution so here it is:

```
$(".accordion").click(function(){
  $(".accordion").removeClass("active");
  $(".accordion").next().css('max-height', '0');
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $(this).next().css('max-height', $(this).next().prop('scrollHeight'));
});
```

See it at work in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sgL2w1xj/3/)

Comment: This is much easier, you have swayed me to use this, and furthermore invest some time into jQuery. One problem, the same I had with the Javascript, How can I set it so the active one can be closed if it is clicked? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly modified version of the code previously posted:
You can close all buttons if you click on one AND it can close the clicked button/accordion again:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName('accordion');
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
acc[i].addEventListener('click', function() { 
    this.classList.toggle('active');
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === 'block') {
    panel.style.display = 'none';
    
    } else {
    panel.style.display = 'block';
        for(let j=0;j<acc.length;j++){
            if(this.classList != acc[j].classList){
                acc[j].classList.remove('active');
                acc[j].nextElementSibling.style.display = 'none';  
            }
        }
    }
});
}
```